# problem returning a local variable in Python function

Tags: python, function

I am a beginner and I am sure this is a simple mistake. I had the program running correctly before I accidentally pasted instead of copied the correct code. The code is supposed to output True if given an odd number and False given an even. Here is what I have modified but still can't get the isOdd value to change to False in the global scope:

```
def odd(x):
  while x%2==0:
    isOdd=False
    return isOdd
isOdd=True
x=42
odd(x)
print(isOdd)
```

Comment: Variables don't work like that - you can't return or pass around variables, and `return some_var` doesn't mean the caller has a `some_var` variable now, or do anything to an existing `some_var` the caller already had.

Comment: Here https://repl.it/repls/FrequentFickleSign#main.py Check this out.

Answer (score 1):

In your main program, you ignored the return value.  Change your code to assign it where you wish.  One important thing to learn is name spaces and variable scoping.  Your program has *two* variables named `isOdd`: one each in the main program and the function.  Python does not link them in any way.

```
# isOdd=True  This line does *not* assign a value inside the function
x=42
isOdd = odd(x)
print(isOdd)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if else is much better to use. Like below in code (in C++) and there no need to use loop, I guess.

```
void number_check(int var1){
if(var1%2==0){
    cout << "Variable Is Even!" << endl;
}else{
    cout << "Variable is Odd!" << endl;
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I was told not to use if statements but use the % operator

Comment: but if We run it in loop then it will not end I guess. Because var1%2==0; will always be true in case of even number

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be simplified to a be only a few characters. 0 evaluates as false in most languages, including Python—any other number evaluates as true. The only thing you need to do is convert the value to a Boolean and return it.

```
def odd(x):
  return bool(x % 2)

x = 42
result = odd(x)
print(result)
```

## Note

Your question includes some errors related to scoping in Python. I suggest you refer to variable scoping documentation and improve understanding of when to use while loops vs if statements.

## References

Python variable scoping: https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html

Answer (score -1):

It can be fixed as following:

```py
def odd(x):
  global isOdd  # Use 'global' keyword
  while x%2==0:
    isOdd=False
    return isOdd
```

But I am not recommend to use global variable declaration

It makes code fragment and hard to read context.

On your case (to know whether is odd), just use by returned.

```
is_odd = odd(x)
```

Comment: No need to use a global here...  rationalizing global here would justify the overuse of globals, generally.

Comment: @pygeek I agree, it is the overuse. it's just one of solutions. but this is simple program that prints True or False if number is odd.